# Developing a ribbon tab in Word 2010, using ampersand symbol in group label name

Tags: xml, user-interface, ms-word, ampersand, word-template

I'm developing a ribbon tab for use in a template (`MyTemplate.dotm`) for Word 2010.

My problem: I want to have an ampersand symbol (&) in the label for a group. I have tried many things, and also alot of googling about this issue, but nothing works:

```
(named)   &amp;
(decimal) &#38;
(decimal) &#038;
(hex)     &#x26;
```

This is what I have tried, the xml saved in `MyTemplate.dotm`-file (with *Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tabMyTemplate" label="myTemplate">

        <group id="grpCopyAndPasteCopy1" label="Copy&amp;Paste 1">
        <!-- HTML Entity (named) &amp; -->
        </group>
        <group id="grpCopyAndPasteCopy2" label="Copy&#38;Paste 2">
        <!-- HTML Entity (decimal) &#38; -->
        </group>
        <group id="grpCopyAndPasteCopy3" label="Copy&#038;Paste 3">
        <!-- HTML Entity (decimal) &#038; -->
        </group>
        <group id="grpCopyAndPasteCopy4" label="Copy&#x26;Paste 4">
        <!-- HTML Entity (hex) &#x26; -->
        </group>

      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Here is the result when open `MyTemplate.dotm` in Word 2010:
[image]

Does anyone know how I should solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, you need "&amp;&amp;"

Comment: Both of your answers were correct @Ken White and @bibadia. I got i to work with `&amp;&amp;` in my markup. If any of you would like to write an answer I would be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common problem when working with standard menu items. A single ampersand (&) is interpreted as the shortcut key (the one that gets underlined when you hold down the Alt key).

To show a literal '&' in the caption, double them: `Copy&&Paste`. For XML, you'll need to escape them useing `&amp;&amp;`. The doubled characters should give you the output you want.

Comment: Just came across this and can confirm they need to be escaped as stated.